# Cannot connect to Oracle database within a Spring Boot application using docker compose

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-boot, docker

I've a Spring boot application which I'd like to connect with an Oracle database, containerised using [Oracle Database Free Container / Docker images.](https://hub.docker.com/r/gvenzl/oracle-free) image.

Additionally, I use docker compose to configure the database deployment and *Spring Boot Docker Compose* to run the deployment on application startup.

However, My application cannot connect to the database due to the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection (CONNECTION_ID=V0w3NC+xSxaZYliy+XojdA==)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.handleLogonNetException(T4CConnection.java:892) ~[ojdbc8-21.9.0.0.jar:21.9.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:697) ~[ojdbc8-21.9.0.0.jar:21.9.0.0.0]
```

The Oracle container looks good:

```
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_FREE)))
2023-12-18T19:40:23.357410157Z Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=0.0.0.0)(PORT=1521)))
2023-12-18T19:40:23.357437163Z 
2023-12-18T19:40:23.357462169Z Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_FREE)))
2023-12-18T19:40:23.377109429Z STATUS of the LISTENER
2023-12-18T19:40:23.377387489Z ------------------------
2023-12-18T19:40:23.377432499Z Alias                     LISTENER
2023-12-18T19:40:23.377468507Z Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 23.0.0.0.0 - Production
2023-12-18T19:40:23.377499514Z Start Date                18-DEC-2023 19:40:23
2023-12-18T19:40:23.377528520Z Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 0 sec
2023-12-18T19:40:23.377556526Z Trace Level               off
2023-12-18T19:40:23.381577398Z Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
2023-12-18T19:40:23.381807448Z SNMP                      OFF
2023-12-18T19:40:23.381845456Z Default Service           FREE
2023-12-18T19:40:23.381875462Z Listener Parameter File   /opt/oracle/product/23c/dbhomeFree/network/admin/listener.ora
2023-12-18T19:40:23.381903469Z Listener Log File         /opt/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/f8cd793dc1d4/listener/alert/log.xml
2023-12-18T19:40:23.381930474Z Listening Endpoints Summary...
2023-12-18T19:40:23.383162742Z   (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_FREE)))
2023-12-18T19:40:23.383223755Z   (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=0.0.0.0)(PORT=1521)))
2023-12-18T19:40:23.383255762Z The listener supports no services
2023-12-18T19:40:23.385380222Z The command completed successfully
2023-12-18T19:40:33.630788572Z ORACLE instance started.
```

Also, the datasource configuration and docker compose setup are inline with `gvenzl/oracle-free:latest` image setup [instructions](https://hub.docker.com/r/gvenzl/oracle-free)

Spring application config:

```yaml
spring:
  liquibase:
    enabled: false
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/FREEPDB1
    username: PERSONS_DB
    password: Lider0ne
```

Docker compose setup

```yaml
services:
  oracle:
    image: 'gvenzl/oracle-free:latest'
    environment:
      - 'ORACLE_RANDOM_PASSWORD=true'
      - 'APP_USER=PERSONS_DB'
      - 'APP_USER_PASSWORD=Lider0ne'
    ports:
      - 1521:1521
```

Finally, I get a similar error connecting to the database using IntelliJ Database tool window.

```
IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection (CONNECTION_ID=gZO5dOjYRGKjaOL469MGIw==).
```

[image]

> **NOTE: I run docker on Apple M chip**
>
> According to [Oracle Database Free](https://hub.docker.com/r/gvenzl/oracle-free) documentation, it shouldn't be problem, I followed its instructions to run the container using [colima](https://github.com/abiosoft/colima) with `--arch -x86_64` option. The container started successfully as explained above.

Have you experienced the same issue? If so, how could I fix it

Answer (score 0):

Docker compose creates a bridged network for you, `docker network ls` ,where service discovery is happening.

localhost is local to your Spring App (and you do not have Oracle Database running in your Spring App container)

```
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/FREEPDB1
```

So, you can access the db by the name of the service `'oracle'` (:1521 is default and can be omitted)

```
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@oracle/FREEPDB1
```

Best of luck!